# Extracting some data from big JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, object

I am getting a JSON response from a WebSocket connection that contains lots of data in JavaScript and this is the response:

```
[
  {
    "e": "type",
    "E": 5000,
    "s": "test1",
    "c": "0",
    "o": "0",
    "h": "0",
    "l": "0",
    "v": "0",
    "q": "0"
  }, {
    "e": "type",
    "E": 10000,
    "s": "test2",
    "c": "0",
    "o": "0",
    "h": "0",
    "l": "0",
    "v": "0",
    "q": "0"
  },
  ...
]
```

and I just need some of it, for example, I need "E" where "s" equals "test2" I think using "for" is wrong because it's a lot of data so how can I do such a thing in javascript I am pretty new at JS.

Comment: Your data is in a JSON array, so you *have* to iterate through it using either an `Array.prototype` method like `find`, `indexOf`, or `filter` - or with a `for` or `for( of )` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const arrayFromJson = [ { "e": "type", .... } ];

const firstTest2 = arrayFromJson.find( o => o['s'] === 'test2' );
if( firstTest2 ) {
    const valueOfE = firstTest2.E;
    console.log( "E: %o", valueOfE );
}
```